# I dont know how to optimize this

Tags: php

Sometimes the fields "con1, con2,..." are empty, thats why i put if everytime:

```
                <?php if ($item['con1']): ?>
                    <ul class="contras">
                            <li><?php echo $item['con1']; ?></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($item['con2']): ?>                
                            <li><?php echo $item['con2']; ?></li>   
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($item['con3']): ?>                
                            <li><?php echo $item['con3']; ?></li>   
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($item['con4']): ?>                
                            <li><?php echo $item['con4']; ?></li>   
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($item['con5']): ?>                
                            <li><?php echo $item['con5']; ?></li>   
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($item['con6']): ?>                
                            <li><?php echo $item['con6']; ?></li>   
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($item['con7']): ?>                
                            <li><?php echo $item['con7']; ?></li>   
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($item['con8']): ?>                
                            <li><?php echo $item['con8']; ?></li>   
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($item['con1']): ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

This code will make a lot of requests? Its possible to optimize it?

Comment: You use extra `if condition` I see. First and second condition is enough for you

Comment: wrong copy & paste, now its Ok.

Comment: Maybe `foreach($item as $i) { echo '<li>' . $i . '</li>'; }`

Comment: @Jose I think you can make it a lot more concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop:

```
<?php if ($item['con1']): ?>
    <ul class="contras">
            <li><?php echo $item['con1']; ?></li>
    </ul>
<?php endif;
      for($i = 2; $i <= 8; $i++):
      if ($item['con'.$i]): ?>                
           <li><?php echo $item['con'.$i]; ?></li>   
<?php endif;
      endfor;
      if ($item['con1']): ?>
   </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yes, i think is a cool way. But maybe in line 4 i should remove "</ul>", no?